# Start server in debug mode won't work on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat

I'm trying to start a jsf application in debug mode but it doesn't work. I've made some modifications on the code, and then it stoped working. i've sent these changes to my friend and it works normally.

Here's the log:

```
07/07/2014 16:48:51 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\;.
07/07/2014 16:48:51 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVISO: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '5' did not find a matching property.
07/07/2014 16:48:51 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVISO: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:solis_web' did not find a matching property.
07/07/2014 16:48:51 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
07/07/2014 16:48:51 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 612 ms
07/07/2014 16:48:51 com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
07/07/2014 16:48:51 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
07/07/2014 16:48:51 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
07/07/2014 16:48:51 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
07/07/2014 16:48:52 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\jvmartins\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\solis_web\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
07/07/2014 16:48:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/shared/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/jvmartins/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/solis_web/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

But if i try to start the server normally, it works. I've tried to clean both the project and the apache server, but it didn't help.

Comment: This log says nothing. The only thing I can think is Eclipse is not properly deploying your application to the server. But that doesn't seem to explain the given symptoms.

Comment: Hmmm...i've been given the same log before but the server would start on debug mode...i don't know what may have caused this...my colleague said to delete the project and download it again from the svn....maybe it'll help...

Comment: Don't think you need such an extreme solution. Just see if you've changed something in your project's *.project* folder or similars.

Comment: I didn't...only changed code from some classes....

Comment: do check if you have added all your build paths in your deployment assembly as well this same happened to me i added my build path entries in deployment assembly and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Delete the jar that deploys to `solis_web\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar`. It conflicts with the version of those classes built into (and provided by) Tomcat. Open the project's Properties dialog and make sure the Server page has it pointing to Tomcat; that should correctly put the APIs in the build path without duplicating them.